# Observables Handling Multiple Fast and Slow

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have an app that initializes on startup and calls many observables. Some observables complete quickly and others slowly. For best performance I'd like to run observables in parallel (where possible) and have subscribe code run immediately (where possible). Some observables are dependent on one or more other observables finishing successfully.

What's the best way or structuring code to achieve this?

The following simplified example seems to be work but my understanding is nested and multiple subscribes are generally bad practice. Also, as the number of observables and inter-dependencies grows there will be more and more subscribes and nested subscribes. Also, there's no guarantee that fast observables will always run fast.

```
this.getAppConfig() // All observables depend on appConfig returning data successfully.
    .flatMap(() => {
        return Observable.of('If I am slow, I will block the final subscribe')
    })
    return Observable.forkJoin(
        Observable.of('If I am slow, I will block the final subscribe'),
        Observable.of('If I am slow, I will block the final subscribe')
     )
    .subscribe(() => {
        Observable.of('slow').subscribe(() => console.log('Do not block other observables'))
        Observable.of('fast').subscribe(() => console.log('Run me as soon as possible'))
        Observable.of('slow').subscribe(() => console.log('Do not block other observables'))
        Observable.of('fast').subscribe(() => console.log('Run me as soon as possible'))
    })
```

Comment: Quick thought: if you have a `forkJoin` but want to do something immediately when one of the observables emits, just add a side effect to them (`do`).

Comment: do all these observable needs to be completed in the init process?

Comment: Many observables need to run/completed in init process e.g. config, translations, user, user config, etc.